# AS3 - Sending POST data to another domain without loading (Sandbox security)

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, post, sandbox

I need to send POST Data to a ASP script on a different domain name ( without loading data).

```
var scriptRequest :URLRequest = new URLRequest( 'http://someExternalCart.com/cart.asp' );
scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
scriptRequest.data = scriptVars;
```

It works with navigateToUrl, BUT I don't want to get redirected to that page, I only want to send the data.

I have tried this:

```
var ldr :URLLoader = new URLLoader();
ldr.load( scriptRequest );
```

But I am getting the sandbox security error.

Is there any other way of sending the data without redirection/page reload and without loading (which causes the security error)?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to the server to add the crossdomain.xml security policy file, you will need to set up a proxy on your own server that passes the request through for you (something like http://xmlrpcflash.mattism.com/proxy_info.php).

Comment: I don't have the access to the server to add the crossdomain policy. I know I could do the proxy, but was hoping that there is some way of doing it straight from flash. Is there no way to do an "invisible" navigateToUrl?

Comment: ...or if there is a way to catch the security error. As I understand the error occurs on the loading part, so sending should work, am I right?

Comment: I don't think you can do a try/catch on an asynchronous event.  In FP 10, you can do some kind of handling on the UnhandledError, and that may be enough to keep it from borking your code (since there is nothing in your code that depends on the result).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid sandbox error, you need a crossdomain file on "http://someExternalCart.com/".

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html

Or you can use a script (php, asp...) on your webserver that will act as a proxy.

http://www.snorkl.tv/2011/04/get-data-into-flash-from-other-domains-with-crossdomain-xml-or-php-proxy-script/

Comment: Thanks soju, I was hoping that I can do it somehow without a proxy. No other ideas? Like some "invisible" navigateToUrl, or sending it via URLLoader's load() and maybe catching the sandbox error?

Comment: I am trying to do a proxy, but having no luck, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167667/problem-with-creating-php-proxy