# Problem with creating php proxy

Tags: php, post, proxy, header, get

I can't get this to work:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://someServer.com/save.asp?';

    $count = 0;

    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) 
    {

        if( $count != 0 ) $url .= "&";

        $url .= urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value);

        $count++;

    } 

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $url;?>">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If I copy the output of the final $url string and paste it in directly in the browser, it works fine.

So it looks like the $url gets built correctly, but there is some problem with the redirection.

// EDIT

I am trying to get this to work:

```
<?php 


$str = '';

$count = 0;

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) 
{
    if( $count != 0 ) $str .= "&";

    //$url .= urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value);
    $str .= $key.'='.$value;

    $count++;
} 


$url = 'http://someDomain.com/acript.asp?'.$str; 


$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);

?>
```

I get: Bad Request

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but this is not a proxy you are writing.
Also, use this instead of the loop - http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: This doesn't proxy anything, It just rebuilds a POST into a GET , which the browser then fetches. A proxy would be the server reaching out to grab a page on behalf the browser.

Comment: I don't want this to work in the browser. So what should I do?

Comment: print file_get_contents($url);

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to work, without relying on the browser to request the page, remove all the HTML and add:

`print file_get_contents($url);`

at the end. if this doesn't work for you (and it may not work for sevral reasons) you will have to use - http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php.

Also to build the right url, you don't have to iterate over $_POST yourself,  use:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

PS 
what ever you are trying to do, this is probably the wrong solution.

Comment: What I am trying to do is: just to send the information to someServer.com/save.asp thorough this script as I can not do this directly, I don't need to fetch anything. I did try print file_get_contents($url); and it doesn't work

Comment: if someServer.com expects to get the information as GET, then this will work.

Comment: Here are the possible pit falls: 
* PHP should be configured to open urls through file_get_contents. I think this is the default.

* someServer.com/save.asp has no special expectations about the request headers.  and it may have, such as user-agent (browser) accepted content etc.

* someServer.com/save.asp does infact expect a GET request.

If the first is not the case you'll have to configure php.ini.


For the others you'll have to more carefully construct your request with cURL.

Comment: what does it print? better yet do var_dump(file_get_contents($url)) if it does not open the url it will return false.

Comment: it does print the page, but, the GET data doesn't seem to get there

Comment: Then it may expect some headers to be set... does it work if you put the $url in a browser? if so then it may expect some common headers. install firebug to view the request headers the browser is sending and emulate them exactly with cURL.

Comment: it returns false. And yes it does when I manually copy and paste the url in the browser

Comment: then it doesn't open the url. check if the url is correct and if your php.ini has somthing like

- allow_url_fopen 1

Comment: allow_url_fopen is ON, the url is correct, it does work if I paste it in the browser

Comment: in any way you can do this with cURL 
it's not too diffcult, check some examples in the comments http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Yossi, I am trying to use cURL, but having a problem again, please see the EDIT above

Answer (score 0):

Ah, your cURL is overly complex, it uses cookies and headers that indicate the request is expecting a an image.
simply try this instead:

```
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

if this still doesn't work, just use firebug to see what are the headers you browser is sending and add them, like this:

```
$headers = array("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
```

Comment: I get: Bad Request please see EDIT above

Comment: acript.asp
is that a typo?
also, please do - $url = "http://someDomain.com/acript.asp?".http_build_query($_POST); instead of the way you build the url. it can avoid many errors.

Comment: The typo doesn't matter, It is only me hiding the real domain. http_build_query for some reason doesn't work. I get a message from someDomain.com that the query is invalid. It works fine without http_built_query perfectly when I copy and paste it in a browser.

Comment: you when you copy it to your broser it does stuff like url encode the url you place, which I notice you didn't do in your code. try wraping the url in urlencode().

Comment: also, in your browser, is this some page you need to gain access to by logging in, perhaps it is expecting a cookie?

Comment: I don't need to log in. But it is a cart where I am sending data, could it require a cookie?

Comment: YES, it probably does.. it probably requires and returns a cookie. this makes it a bit more complex. again you can check the firebug request and response headers (a cookie is sent with headers) to see if you need to send a cookie and wheater one is being returned. Emulating this with cURL is possible, but you will need to save state by saving the cookie and updating it if when needed.

Comment: Also, there is a fundamental thing I don't get, you want to add things to a shopping cart of an unregistered user through PHP...? you know this will not be useful for anyone, right? you will need to have the cookie the site returns in order to view the shopping cart... this kind of proxy will be of no use to anyone because the end user using the proxy will not have this cookie, and hence will not have access to the shopping cart. You can not plant the cookie the site returns to the client using your proxy, because it will register on a different domain.

Comment: The cookie the shopping cart returns is what identifies link your session to your the shopping cart. which when done through PHP (server side) is NOT the client (the browser doing the original POST)  session. and you can not make it so...

Comment: I am lost, It orignally started here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161839/as3-sending-post-data-to-another-domain-without-loading-sandbox-security I am not sure how I can get round this now :(

Comment: Thank you for your help and time Yossi, very much appreciated

Comment: Basically you are trying to forge a request to the web-site. you can try doing this by using something like img tags to request the url - you can create them dynamically using js - since this is a request by the broser - it should send and receive cookies accordingly. however theee is no grantee this will work and it may not work for many reasons.